# Accessing global variable in angular2 component sometimes gives ReferenceError not defined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use google materials in my angular, which involves calling this:

`componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();`

when the page changes (e.g. dynamically adding a text box) to update the control styling.

I have multiple components calling `componentHandler`. Originally, I declared it at the top of my component like this:

```
(MyBigComponent.ts)
declare var componentHandler: any;
```

This worked perfectly, until I wanted to add another component called `MyNestedComponent` which is rendered onto MyBigComponent using `*ngIf` in a div.

I therefore added it to `MyNestedComponent`:

```
(MyNestedComponent.ts)
declare var componentHandler: any;
```

This also worked.

The workflow for my app is:

> AppComponent > MyBigComponent > MyNestedComponent

Following this workflow works fine. AppComponent has a routerLink anchor to `/MyBigComponent` which renders it to the `<router-outlet>`. Once MyBigComponent is filled in and they press a button, MyNestedComponent appears.

If however I go straight to MyBigComponent, by typing into my browser `www.mysite.com/MyBigComponent` instead of clicking the hyperlink, MyBigComponent works fine, but upon clicking the button, MyNestedComponent gives me the error:

`ReferenceError: componentHandler is not defined`

I have tried moving around the declaration to various files such as my `app.component.ts` and `app.module.ts` but I continue to get the same error when going directly to the URL.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: if you are calling `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()` on `ngOnInit` move it to `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've given it a go but the same issue - it gives me that error when I use the route...